# Ссылка в интернет C#

Tags: c#

Интересует такой вопрос. Можно ли в коде как-то задать ссылку в интернет? Буду благодарен.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     linkLabel1.Text = "HashCode.ru";
     this.linkLabel1.Links[0].LinkData = "http://hashcode.ru/";
}

private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{            
     linkLabel1.Links[linkLabel1.Links.IndexOf(e.Link)].Visited = true;
     string target = e.Link.LinkData as string;
     if (null != target && (target.StartsWith("http") || target.StartsWith("www")))
          System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
     else
          MessageBox.Show("Item clicked: " + target);            
}
```